# Facebook IM service?

Tags: software-installation, facebook

In an older time, there was pidgin and empathy and several others, but none of them are supported any more. I have recently grown tired of logging in to Facebook just to check if i have any messages when I use my laptop. Any program suggestions or links are appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/dequis/purple-facebook/wiki

Comment: @_@ Didn't specify that I use Ubuntu 14.04
 Also don't use NIX

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/dequis/purple-facebook/wiki :

The purple-facebook plugin is a replacement for the builtin Facebook XMPP plugin. Facebook is in the process of shutting down their XMPP service, which will inevitably break existing support.

As part of Google Summer of Code (GSoC) 2015, jgeboski worked on a plugin for libpurple to support the newer Facebook Messenger protocol. The plugin is implemented for the development version of libpurple, purple3, which has yet to be released. The purple-facebook project simply back-ports the purple3 plugin to purple2, which is the released version of libpurple.

As of October 18, 2015, jgeboski's GSoC work was merged into the mainline Pidgin project. It will appear in the next major release of Pidgin.

**Install [instructions](https://jgeboski.github.io/#package-repositories):**

Add the following line to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jgeboski.list:

> deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jgeboski/
>   ./

Notes:

In this case, replace  with your Ubuntu version: trusty

> deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jgeboski/trusty
>   ./

Add the repository key:

> $ wget -O- https://jgeboski.github.io/obs.key | sudo apt-key add -

Update the package index:

> sudo apt-get update

Install the plugin:

> sudo apt-get install